# Delete an account record using id in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

Help me about deleting an account record as one of the admin in the system.
it's like I'm managing an accounts.

---

For example.

```
User-1 [Update] [Delete]
User-2 [Update] [Delete]
User-3 [Update] [Delete]
User-4 [Update] [Delete]
```

---

and I want to delete User-3.

---

### Controller (login)

```
public function delete($id = '') {
$this->load->model('User_model');
$this->User_model->delete_id($id);
```

---

### Model (User_model)

```
public function delete_id ($id) {
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->delete('user'); 
redirect('users', 'refresh');
}
```

**db table name = user**

Help me please I'm still noob in codeigniter.

Comment: You should add more details: What isn't working? What did you try etc.

Comment: it's like I'm managing an accounts. For example. User-1, User-2, User-3, User-4 and I want to delete User-3.

Answer (score 0):

try putting this on your delete link on your view. This will give the id value to the function that will delete the user.

```
<a href='<?=base_url();?>login/delete/<?php echo $id;?>'>delete</a>
```

On your controller you must edit the following from

```
public function delete($id = '') {
$this->load->model('User_model');
$this->User_model->delete_id($id);
```

to this

```
public function delete() {
$id = $this->uri->segment(3); //this will get the value from the localhost/login/delete/user1
//$id == 'user1'
$this->load->model('User_model');
$this->User_model->delete_id($id);
```

Comment: It says **An Error Was Encountered

_The URI you submitted has disallowed characters._**

Comment: bro can you give me the name of the controller where you put the `delete` function?

Comment: it's **login.php** @Lee Balino

Comment: @StillLearning try this one `<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>login/delete/<?php echo $id;?>">Delete</a>`. This is just a sample code. I assume that the `login` was the name of the controller and inside that controller is the function `delete`. the `$id` was the value passed by the controller to the `view`

Comment: @StillLearning try to replace also the

`public function delete($id = '')`

to

`public function delete($id)`

Comment: Is my code in controller correct? I want have a function in the controller that gets the id then delete. @Lee Balino

Comment: @StillLearning you can try this code on your function so you can get the value without the error. just add this before the lines of code. `$id = $this->uri->segment(3);` I will update my answer for you to able to follow what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
user3 <a href="login/deleteuser/<?php echo $id;?>"
```

controller

```
public function deleteuser($id){
  $result=$this->User_model->delete_id($id);
  if($result==1){
     echo 'success';
  }else{
     echo 'failed';
  }    
}
```

model

```
 public function delete_id($id){
    $this->db->where("userId",$id);
    $this->db->delete("users");
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

where userId is the name of the id column in users table, and users is the name of the table